# Using Ajax to story response variable for php login

Tags: php, html, ajax

Ok so, some context. My college started doing some "learning on the job" type classes, and it's becoming a pain because it's like an internship without any sort of capacitation. Just my luck I was assigned a project I'm barely prepared for.

Right now I've been asked to join together an old Jamit Job Board with the login system of the place. Basically verify first if the user exist in the test database, then check if they exist in the local jobboard database. The problem is I don't have any ajax experience since it's not a topic we have touched in my classes. Sad, I know.

I was trying using cURL but was told by the supervisor it wouldn't work.

```
public function validar_request($Username,$Password) {

    $Username = ($_REQUEST['username']);
    $Password = md5(stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']));

    function httpGet($url,p){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$respuesta1 = httpGet("http://www01pruebasweb.fod.ac.cr/upe/templates/interfaces/ConexionFramework.php?procedimiento=nombreUsuarioExiste&username=".$Username);
```

The URL will return a 1 is the user exists in the testing database, 0 if not. I was thinking on doing a series of If else that if response = 1, then proceed to login, else don´t since its like a 3 step verification process. First if the user exists, then if the password exists, and lastly if both tables in both databases match.

Response I get in the browser looks like [this.](http://www01pruebasweb.fod.ac.cr/upe/templates/interfaces/ConexionFramework.php?procedimiento=nombreUsuarioExiste&username=usuario_01)

If the user usuario_01 exists then I should get a one. The idea me and a teammate had was to use curl to store the 1 into a variable in php and compare it but it's not working. Specially with the mess that is, for me, the other code for logging of Jamit. I mainly have experience with Java, not web development so as you can understand I'm very overwelmed.

I was trying to contact support from Jamit to see if they had any help, but they aren't active since 2013. Though not sure how much help they would be.

Not sure if necessary but part of the code for logging of Jamit is this

```
function validate_candidate_login($login_page='') {

global $login_output;
if ($login_output)  { echo $login_output; return; } // this function was buffered

if ($login_page=='') {
    $login_page = JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER."index.php";
}



global $label;

$Username = ($_REQUEST['username']);
$Password = md5(stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']));
$sql = "Select * From users Where Username='".jb_escape_sql($Username)."'";
$result = JB_mysql_query($sql);

// init $row
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    $row = array();
} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
JBPLUG_do_callback('val_can_set_pass', $Password); // Note for Plugin authors: Password is passed by refrence. Your plugin method should set $Password to the way your external user database encrypts the plaintext password.. eg $Password = md5($_REQUEST['password']); for phpBB

JBPLUG_do_callback('val_can_login', $row); // Note for Plugin authors: $row argument is passed by reference, which is the row of your users table. The row is populated if username/pass are valid, $row['Username'] and $row['Password'] are set for the code below and should come from your external database. You may also set $row['Validated'] too  

if ((!$row['Username']) && ($_REQUEST['silent']=='')) {

    $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%LOGIN_PAGE%', $login_page, $label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
    $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%FORGOT_PAGE%',JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER."forgot.php",$label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
    $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%SIGNUP_PAGE%',JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER."signup.php",$label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);

    echo '<p style="text-align:center; ">'.$label["c_login_invalid_msg"]."</p>";
} else {
    if ($row['Validated']=="0") {
        $label["c_login_notvalidated"] = str_replace('%BASE_HTTP_PATH%', JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH,  $label["c_login_notvalidated"]);
        echo '<p style="text-align:center; ">'.$label["c_login_notvalidated"].'</p>';
    } else {
        if (($Password === $row['Password']) || ((JB_ALLOW_ADMIN_LOGIN=='YES')&&(JB_ADMIN_PASSWORD===$_REQUEST['password']))) {

            JBPLUG_do_callback('val_can_login_sync', $row); // Note for Plugin authors: Initialize $row with a Jamit user row. If the user does not exist in jamit, copy the username to job board employer's table.

            JBPLUG_do_callback('val_can_login_set_session', $row); // Note for Plugin authors: set session variables for your external database (successful login)

            JB_set_candidate_session($row); // set session for the candidate


            $label['c_login_welcome'] = str_replace ("%FNAME%", JB_escape_html($_SESSION['JB_FirstName']), ($label['c_login_welcome']));
            $label['c_login_welcome'] = str_replace ("%LNAME%", JB_escape_html($_SESSION['JB_LastName']), ($label['c_login_welcome']));
            $label['c_login_welcome'] = str_replace ("%USERNAME%", JB_escape_html($_SESSION['JB_Username']), ($label['c_login_welcome']));

            if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
                $label['c_login_welcome'] = preg_replace('/index\.php/i', htmlentities($_REQUEST['page']), $label['c_login_welcome']);
            }

            if ($_REQUEST['silent']=='') {
                echo '<p style="text-align:center; ">'.$label["c_login_welcome"].'</p>';
            }
        } else {

            $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%LOGIN_PAGE%', htmlentities($login_page), $label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
            $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%FORGOT_PAGE%',JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER."forgot.php",$label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
            $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('%SIGNUP_PAGE%',JB_BASE_HTTP_PATH.JB_CANDIDATE_FOLDER."signup.php",$label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
            if (strpos($login_page, 'apply_iframe.php')!==false) {
                $label["c_login_invalid_msg"] = str_replace('_parent', '_self', $label["c_login_invalid_msg"]);
            }
            echo '<div style="text-align:center;">'.$label["c_login_invalid_msg"].'</div>';
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make this question much more concise. What specific things are you having trouble with?

Comment: Ok, I guess mainly is using ajax to store the result from the request from the URL into something I can use in php to compare values. If 1 do this, or else do that, basically. I don´t mind if its just ajax documentation, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok cool - per the comments you're looking to get started with AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML). I would highly recommend linking jQuery to your html page to get started - it will make AJAX calls MUCH easier.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Awesome, now we have jQuery loaded, which allows you to make an ajax call with a simple function.

So now we need to get values from the browser to the server. How do we do that? There are 2 approaches I would recommend:

1 - Use JSON (Javascript Object Notation) to send data to the server with key/value pairs. PHP is great for working with JSON.

2 - Serialize a form using jQueries $(formElement).serialize() function. This turns forms into key/value pairs and you can then receive the data using PHPs $_POST['keyOfFormField']

So I'm going to assume you're going with the JSON approach, which is always preferable in my opinion.

If you're unfamiliar with javascript, JSON format looks like this:

```
var jsonExample = {'Im a key': 'and im its value'};
```

This is how you represent an object literal in javascript, and we can send these to the server and store them in an associative array in PHP.

So, on to the ajax call. I will leave it up to you to research ways of getting your data into JSON format. It should be really simple.

In jQuery, an AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'urlOfServerFile.php',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({'Im a key': 'Im its value'}),
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            json = JSON.parse(json);

            //The server sent you back some data, do something with it!

        },
        error: function () {

            alert("Please check your internet connection and try again");
        }
    });
```

So what is this doing?

$.ajax() is a function. In jQuery, you basically get access to this really awesome object, which is the jQuery object (it's also represented by the $ sign). So, $.ajax() is the same thing as saying jQuery.ajax()

The $.ajax() function takes an object as an argument. Remember that the {} is how we encapsulate an object in javascript.

The documentation for this object can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Basically, we need to tell the $.ajax() function a few things:

url - where are we sending this request?

async - will this request be sent asynchronously?

data - what data are we sending to the server?

type - what type of HTTP request are we sending this data in (POST, PUT, GET, etc)

datatype - what type of data are we sending?

success - what do we do if the request is successful?

error - what do we do if the request fails?

Well, at this point we've successfully sent data from browser to server asynchronously. How do we handle this in PHP? Here's how:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

This variable, $input is now an associative array with all of the JSON key/value pairs that we sent over. So, now we can store some of those values in variables like this:

```
$randomVariable = $input['im a key'];
```

I hope this post will get you started with AJAX. Once you get the hang of it, it's a really intuitive technology that will make your applications WAY better.

Comment: Ok so I have a question. This module I'm editing has not HTML files to use, the index is a php file. Can I use AJAX with the PHP or do I need to create a new HTML file, because I'm afraid to mess this code up.

Comment: Ok so first you REALLY  need to be using a version control system like git + github if you're editing someone else's code so that you can always revert to the original if you need to. Secondly, yes, ajax can be done using a javascript file (.js). I suggest reading more about AJAX documentation and talking to your teacher. If my answer helped at all an upvote would be appreciated!